Subset sum problem with selection constraint in large R dataset
I have a tibble:
sample_tibble <- tibble(
    group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4),
    threshold = c(100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 150, 150, 150, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200),
    id = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "D", "A", "B", "C", "A", "D", "E", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "D"),
    value = c(10, 5, 20, 90, 40, 90, 5, 1, 10, 60, 50, 10, 10, 10, 32, 70, 100, 120, 50, 15)
)

sample_tibble
# A tibble: 20 × 4
   group threshold id    value
   <dbl>     <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
 1     1       100 A        10
 2     1       100 B         5
 3     1       100 C        20
 4     1       100 A        90
 5     1       100 D        40
 6     2        80 A        90
 7     2        80 B         5
 8     2        80 C         1
 9     2        80 A        10
10     2        80 D        60
11     2        80 E        50
12     3       150 A        10
13     3       150 B        10
14     3       150 C        10
15     4       200 A        32
16     4       200 B        70
17     4       200 C       100
18     4       200 A       120
19     4       200 B        50
20     4       200 D        15

As shown, each group is given one threshold, and has multiple ids. There can be more than 1 id appearing, but the values differ.
The goal is to select ids until the sum of values is the closest to the threshold; hence, unlike typical Knapsack problem, the sum of values of selected ids can exceed threshold, if the summed value is optimally the closest to the threshold for that group.
The caveat is, for each group, the same id cannot be selected twice.
The solution (in the form of table, ideally) I am looking for would be the following:
solution_tibble
# A tibble: 12 × 4
   group threshold id    value
   <dbl>     <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
 1     1       100 B         5
 2     1       100 A        90
 3     2        80 B         5
 4     2        80 C         1
 5     2        80 A        10
 6     2        80 D        60
 7     3       150 A        10
 8     3       150 B        10
 9     3       150 C        10
10     4       200 A        32
11     4       200 B        70
12     4       200 C       100

Now, this could be done by checking out all powersets and their sums, but the issue is the actual data I'm working with is some hundreds of thousands of groups, and some millions of corresponding ids.
I would like to discuss the optimal way to solve this variation of subset sum problem for a huge dataset.
(I only currently have the greedy Algorithm set up, which obviously does not guarantee the optimal-ness of the sum of selected ids)

At most, how many unique ids are in a group in your actual dataset? What is the largest group size?

@jblood94 largest group size is around 60k, unique id around 25k. I have around 140k groups.

That is a very large problem, computationally, to find the global optimum. Are the values in your actual problem also integer (or otherwise discrete)?

@jblood94 they are actually continuous numeric (float) values.

So, many instances of the NP-complete subset sum, with float values so that dynamic programming doesn't work.

I think it could be interpreted as an "Integer Programming" optimization problem, but constrained by the uniqueness of id per group.
I am not sure how efficient the solution would be in your scaled-up dataset, but you might be inspired a bit if you look into how CVXR helps to solve the problem.

First, you could define a custom function f, which applies each group
library(CVXR)

f <- function(df) {
    th <- unique(df$threshold)
    vals <- with(df, split(value, id))
    id <- names(vals)
    d <- expand.grid(vals)
    x <- Variable(ncol(d), boolean = TRUE)
    cost <- Inf
    for (i in seq_len(nrow(d))) {
        C <- as.matrix(d[i, ])
        result <- solve(Problem(Minimize(abs(C %*% x - th))))
        if (result$value < cost) {
            msk <- round(result$getValue(x)) > 0
            out <- data.frame(unique(df$group), th, id[msk], C[msk])
            cost <- result$value
        }
    }
    setNames(out, names(df))
}

Then, you split sample_tibble and run f for each group
sample_tibble %>%
    group_split(group) %>%
    map(f) %>%
    bind_rows()

and you will obtain
   group threshold id value
1      1       100  A    90
2      1       100  B     5
3      2        80  A    10
4      2        80  B     5
5      2        80  C     1
6      2        80  D    60
7      3       150  A    10
8      3       150  B    10
9      3       150  C    10
10     4       200  A    32
11     4       200  B    70
12     4       200  C   100


You could calculate the cumsum for value—group combinations, then subset for the minimum absolute differences using aves. Since the interaction group—id has empty elements (check with(sampledf, interaction(group, id))), this produces warnings, which we might suppress.
> sampledf |> within({
+   cum_value <- ave(value, group, id, FUN=cumsum)
+   flag <- as.logical(
+     ave(abs(cum_value - threshold), group, id, FUN=\(x) x == min(x)) |> 
+       suppressWarnings()
+   )
+ }) |> subset(flag, select=-flag)
   group threshold id value cum_value
2      1       100  B     5         5
3      1       100  C    20        20
4      1       100  A    90       100
5      1       100  D    40        40
6      2        80  A    90        90
7      2        80  B     5         5
8      2        80  C     1         1
10     2        80  D    60        60
11     2        80  E    50        50
12     3       150  A    10        10
13     3       150  B    10        10
14     3       150  C    10        10
17     4       200  C   100       100
18     4       200  A   120       152
19     4       200  B    50       120
20     4       200  D    15        15


Unfortunately, this seems to treat in the individual id-scale, instead of the group-scale. As shown in the example, I want to select multiple ids if necessary (just not duplicate id in the same group) to get as close as possible to the group's threshold.

This solution is very similar to Thomas's with an added constraint for the uniqueness of the ids.
For each group, we want to minimize abs(th - sum(C%*%x)) where th is the threshold, C is the value vector, and x is a boolean vector that identifies the id such that there are no duplicates. We can define the constraint by ensuring that the x indicies which are duplicated (if any) do not sum to more than 1.
library(dplyr)
library(CVXR)

make_constraints <- function(df, x) {
  dups <- sum(duplicated(df$id))
  df$rid <- seq_along(df$id)
  df <- arrange(df, id) |>
    mutate(cid=consecutive_id(id))

  if(dups>0)
    lapply(1:dups, \(i) sum(x[df$rid[df$cid==i]]) <= 1)
  else
    list() # no constraints
}

f <- function(df) {
  x <- Variable(nrow(df), boolean=TRUE)
  C <- t(df$value)
  th <- unique(df$threshold)

  objective <- Minimize(abs(th - C%*%x))

  constraints <- make_constraints(df, x)

  prob <- Problem(objective, constraints)
  res <- solve(prob)
  
  df[which(res$getValue(x)==1),]
}

Call the function:
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(sample_tibble, ~group), f))

Giving:
# A tibble: 12 × 4
   group threshold id    value
 * <dbl>     <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
 1     1       100 B         5
 2     1       100 A        90
 3     2        80 B         5
 4     2        80 C         1
 5     2        80 A        10
 6     2        80 D        60
 7     3       150 A        10
 8     3       150 B        10
 9     3       150 C        10
10     4       200 A        32
11     4       200 B        70
12     4       200 C       100


good technique of using make_constraints for the constraint, +1!

Thanks @ThomasIsCoding. Your comments and answers continue to inspire.
